# Abstract classes share properties, any way to put them in one place?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have two abstract classes that has couple of same properties. How can I put them in just one common place?

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
     public abstract string PropertyA {get; }
     public abstract string PropertyB {get; }          
     public string PropertyX {get; set;}
     public void MethodA()
     {
         // do something
     }          
}


public abstract class ClassB
{
     public abstract string PropertyA {get; }
     public abstract string PropertyB {get; }          
     public string PropertyY {get; set;}          
     public void MethodB()
     {
         // do something else
     }
}

public class ClassC1 : ClassA
{
     public string PropertyA {get {return "MyString";} }
     public string PropertyB {get{return "MyOtherString";} }          

}

public class ClassC2 : ClassA
{
     public string PropertyA {get {return "MyString2";} }
     public string PropertyB {get{return "MyOtherString2";} }          

}

public class ClassD1 : ClassB
{
     public string PropertyA {get {return "MyString";} }
     public string PropertyB {get{return "MyOtherString";} }          
}

public class ClassD2 : ClassB
{
     public string PropertyA {get {return "MyString2";} }
     public string PropertyB {get{return "MyOtherString2";} }          
}
```

This is my scenario. Now since PropertyA and PropertyB returns the same value for both class, I was wondering if there's any way I can refactor the classes so I don't have put the same properties in both abstract/concrete classes.

Comment: Third property is string for both abstract classes. I think basically you need only one abstract class.

Comment: i put the third property there just to show there are other properties and methods in the abstract class, probably it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Make a common abstract class with and inherit rest from that

```
public abstract class ClassCommon
{
     public abstract string PropertyA {get; }
     public abstract string PropertyB {get; }          
}

public abstract class ClassA : ClassCommon
{              
     public string PropertyX {get; set;}          
}


public abstract class ClassB : ClassA
{     public string PropertyY {get; set;}          
}
```

You can override the properties instead of using base class properties.

```
public class ClassC1 : ClassCommon
{
     public override string PropertyA {get {return "MyString";} }
     public override string PropertyB {get{return "MyOtherString";} }              
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of putting those properties in another abstract class, but that won't serve my purpose since ClassA and ClassB have some method that my ClassC1 and ClassD1 have to access. And at the same time ClassC1/D1 returning the same value for the properties. I want to encapsulate that return statement.

Comment: Methods were not present in your original post. You can arrange the methods in base-derived classes as we did for properties. You can also think about have having new abstract class for methods.

Comment: yes i added those later for this conversation. So far it looks like I can put the properties in one place. but I still have to pass the value from two different places :(

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't remove the string properties from the sub classes, it does however remove the duplicate string values.

Now they can be configured in "CustomProperties" class once then reused.

See below.

**Favour Composition over inheritance**

```
public class CustomProperties
{
    public string PropertyA { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; private set; }
}

public interface ICustomProperties
{
      string PropertyA { get; }
      string PropertyB { get; }
}

public abstract class ClassA : ICustomProperties
{
    private readonly CustomProperties properties;

    public ClassA(CustomProperties properties)
    {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public string PropertyA
    {
        get { return properties.PropertyA; }
    }

    public string PropertyB
    {
        get { return properties.PropertyB; }
    }

    public string PropertyX { get; set; }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because the notion of a Property in the way you show it seems to be more often used in a "has a" way (Class X has a Property Y). "Has a" is composition.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adil answer, Can you make your methods abstract or virtual and override them in your derived class?

Comment: no i can't do that. it's just those two properties that can be made virtual/abstract

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if ClassA and B can derive from the same base, but if yes you can go like this:

```
public class CommonAB
{
    public string PropertyA { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; private set; }

    public CommonAB(string a, string b)
    {
        PropertyA = a;
        PropertyB = b;
    }
}

public class ClassA : CommonAB
{
    public ClassA(string a, string b)
        : base(a, b)
    {
    }

    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
    public void MethodA()
    {
        // do something
    }
}


public class ClassB : CommonAB
{
    public ClassB(string a, string b)
        : base(a, b)
    {
    }

    public string PropertyY { get; set; }
    public void MethodB()
    {
        // do something else
    }
}

public class ClassC1 : ClassA
{
    public ClassC1()
        : base("MyString", "MyOtherString")
    {
    }
}

public class ClassC2 : ClassA
{
    public ClassC2()
        : base("MyString2", "MyOtherString2")
    {
    }
}

public class ClassD1 : ClassB
{
    public ClassD1()
        : base("MyString", "MyOtherString")
    {
    }
}

public class ClassD2 : ClassB
{
    public ClassD2()
        : base("MyString2", "MyOtherString2")
    {
    }
}
```